# Variable value only visible in "then" promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a "then" function where I declare a variable inside of it and return it. I console log the value inside of the "then" function and get a URL (https://...) but the value outside of the "then" is instead a "object Promise". See the code below

```
let url =  settings.CountryUrl().then(async (url) => {
    console.log("country url in QL " + url) // URL value
   urlcc = url
return urlcc = url
});


console.log(url) /// object Promise value
```

How do I get the value out of the "then" function (URL) and not the object promise? I cannot change the function "CountryUrl" since several other functions depend on it.

Comment: TL;DR: You don't. You work with the value in the `then` callback.

Comment: `async` before the callback is not needed here.